# PyCharm: how to properly attach to a local process for debugging purposes

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, process, pycharm

Hi following the document available for PyCharm here:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/attaching-to-local-process.html I would like to attach to a local process for debugging purposes.

So I just wrote some dummy code in my running.py file without any real-world purpose just for the sake of the demonstration:

```
import time

var_not_in_loop_below = 78
counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    if counter <= 1:
        dummy_text = "Dummy"
    else:
        dummy_text = "Dummies"
    print(str(counter) + " " + dummy_text)
    time.sleep(2)
    loop_var = 42
```

I can attach to the script via Pycharm that I started in a windows cmd: python running.py

However, PyCharm just shows what it's actually printed in the console part without me being able to step in any sort of fashion in source code available in Pycharm, any idea about why I cannot step or debug my code when adding a breakpoint while the interpreter is running the script in the cmd right beside the IDE?

Thanks

[EDIT]
What's going on in the cmd:

```
$  C:\Python278\python.exe running.py  
1 Dummy                                
2 Dummies                              
3 Dummies                              
4 Dummies                              
5 Dummies                              
6 Dummies                              
7 Dummies                              
8 Dummies                              
9 Dummies                              
10 Dummies                             
11 Dummies                             
12 Dummies                             
13 Dummies                             
14 Dummies                             
15 Dummies                             
16 Dummies
```

And in Pycharm

```
Attaching to a process with PID=8620
C:\Python278\python.exe C:\Users\eperret\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-C\ch-0\171.3780.115\helpers\pydev\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py --port 62090 --pid 8620
Connecting to 32 bits target
Injecting dll
Dll injected
Allocating code in target process
Writing code in target process
Allocating return value memory in target process
Injecting code to target process
Waiting for code to complete
Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.3780.115)
Error when injecting code in target process. Error code: 7 (on windows)
10 Dummies
11 Dummies
12 Dummies
13 Dummies
14 Dummies
15 Dummies
16 Dummies
```

Wondering whether the issue is related to this line below:

```
Error when injecting code in target process. Error code: 7 (on windows)
```

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint?

Comment: @thebjorn I did

Comment: works for me (PyCharm 2017.1, Python 2.7.11, breakpoint at `coutner += 1`

Comment: @thebjorn I edited my post, there is an error once the Pycharm is connected to Pydevd debugger: 
"Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.3780.115)"
"Error when injecting code in target process. Error code: 7 (on windows)"

Comment: I have the exact same PyCharm version. My second line in the console is different: `C:\srv\venv\dev\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd_attach_to_process\attach_pydevd.py" --port 63895 --pid 22908`, and of course the last line (`Attach finished successfully.`).

Comment: I tried a couple of more times, and it failed when I had zombie Python processes hanging around. Maybe if you go in task manager and kill the process tree of all Python processes before starting over..?

Comment: @thebjorn gonna logout login let's if I keep bumping into that issue when there is not a single other process around. Just tried same old, same old aww